# Phone always goes to TWRP recovery when powered on

Tags: twrp, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I just recently installed/flashed TWRP Recovery on my rooted Samsung Galaxy S6 running Android 5.1.1 with no custom rom.

TWRP Recovery runs fine I assume (haven't tried any features), although whenever I now boot up my phone it goes straight to TWRP recovery. I definitely do not want this, help?

How I installed TWRP Recovery:

1. Downloaded and installed Flashify from Play Store
2. Opened Flashify and selected Install Recovery (or similar) and selected TWRP
3. Downloaded ..forgot.. It ended with .img
4. Pressed "Yup!" To flashing it
5. Pressed "Reboot Now"

I don't really know much about flashing stuff/TWRP and really any advanced root stuff. How do I make my phone not boot into TWRP Recovery every time (I can't access my phone now...)
**Phone's model number: SM-G920I**

Answer (score 1):

### **DM-Verity**

---

> "This device uses dm-verity!
>   This means that swiping to allow system modifications will prevent you from being able to boot if you are using the stock kernel. In order to bypass dm-verity's boot prevention, you will have to install a kernel that has dm-verity disabled in the fstab."

DM-Verity Reference: https://twrp.me/devices/samsunggalaxys6.html

Is most likely the culprit here.  What this does is run a check on boot and if you are using the stock kernel and it sees a different recovery or even ROM than DM-Verity expects it will not allow you to boot the OS and only recovery so that you can put the official OS and recovery back.  The only way to fix this is to use a custom kernel (or custom ROM that includes a custom kernel),

OR of course if you were to do a full factory image flash (using ODiN you visit Samsung site and get the Factory image meant for your device (be sure model matches your phone's before downloading), put device in download mode and run Odin to flash the factory image.  Of course you will lose root and the custom recovery this way, but it should boot.

Since you did not include your actual model number I hesitate to link just any ROM or Kernel as they may be intended for another variety of the S6.  If you would like comment or edit your question and add the SM-blah model number and I can be of more help in linking ROMs/Kernels (not really what this site is for, but if you need those to get your phone basically running I can at least find the most popular variety of what you need which should hopefully get you working again.  Yuo can google SM-blah ROM XDA and that should give you links to the XDA forums for your device.  They are very well know community that does custom Android work of all kinds.  I can't say it enough make sure you verify your phone's SM-blah model number against the developers ROM info page to make sure it is actually meant to be used with the exact version of the S6 you have.

**Possibly Flashify (DOUBT IT)**
Flashify selected the wrong partition automatically (it does warn you to verify it chose the right partition before flash), so you would need to flash a ROM and start again (Flash ROM, GApps AND Recovery.zip [https://twrp.me/devices/samsunggalaxys6.html])  DO NOT FORGET TO FLASH THE RECOVERY IF IT IS IN WRONG PLACE YOU NEED TO GET IT IN RIGHT PLACE BEFORE RESTARTING AFTER FLASHING THE OS IF NOT YOU MAY LOSE THE RECOVERY.

Comment: Added my phone's model number at the end of my question. I will be more than happy to use a custom kernel/rom. I was kinda assuming I could get away with it because I used an auto-root kernel to root my phone, so I thought I could get away with it.

Comment: Well auto root gives you root and it may also include a kernel, but that would most likely be a separate run through from the root procedure (though it could copy a kernel during root.  Also if your phone has had an update and is using a different version of Android may need an updated utility.  You have root though or no super user and you would have failed the recovery flash.  Is it TWRP or stock recovery when it boots now?  On it with model hold for more info.

Comment: Hmm? I didn't do anything yet, so it's still TWRP? I have SuperSU (chainfire). Also haven't updated my phone (5.1.1) since rooting it.

Comment: Here is a ROM I would suggest if you are just getting started.  It is a modified stock ROM [Marshmallow]: http://bestandroidstuffs.com/install-android-6-0-1-xtrestolite-rom-on-galaxy-s6-sm-g920i/
Another one is a port of S7 Edge ROM giving you all the features S7 Edge has: http://www.teamandroid.com/2016/04/08/install-android-601-noblerom-galaxy-s6-g920i-marshmallow-custom-rom/  and finally a CM13 [unofficial]: http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s6/development/rom-galaxy-s6unofficial-cyranogenmod-t3434849

Comment: Here is just a custom kernel (modified stock) if all you wanted to try was just to swap out the kernel: http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s6/development/rom-tyrannus-rom-v1-0-31-07-2015-t3169760  Finally the XDA Forums [JUST BE SURE TO ALWAYS CHECK TO MAKE SURE WHATEVER YOU DOWNLOAD IS FOR THE SM-920I] as this section of their forums covers about 15-20 different versions of the S6: http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s6

Comment: How do I download the files for the Marshmallow ROM and add them to my phone storage if I can't access my phone or is it possible to access it via PC (even with lock screen enabled)? Also, what data is being deleted when I do a factory reset from TWRP?

Comment: Well you have several options if you can use Micro SD card you could remove it from phone use adapter and plug in to computer copy files and put back in phone.  TWRP should have a file manager and I believe even allows you to mount storage over USB cable to computer if you check in it's settings.   You could use an adapter which enables you to plug USB drive into your charge port (usually like under $5) if your device and/or recovery supports USB OTG (Probably does).

Worst case you need to manually boot to download mode and use Odin (will need ODIN ROM image frm XDA forums or Google search)

Comment: SOO worst case is you find the XDA unbrick thread with your Factory ROM in an image meant for use with Odin then download that and the right Odin version (should be whole thread with instructions on how).  Then Connect USB from computer to phone do manual button press boot method to get to download mode open Odin (with admin rights), open image file with Odin and then flash.  This will be a full factory image without root.  You could pre-collect everything then use same root method and when you get recovery on boot then flash custom stuff.

That should make sense I hope.

Comment: http://www.gizmoadvices.com/unbrick-unroot-galaxy-s6-and-galaxy-s6-edge/ should be what you need. They say unroot in the title, but they have you do that by flashing the factory image so really this is how to unbrick your Samsung S6

Comment: "Unbricking" the device seems to be a good option, but what will it change, eg Change back to Stock Recovery, change kernel? Because I rooted my phone using an auto-root kernel, will it mess up if I change my kernel? And, afterwards, can I install a custom rom and then reinstall TWRP Recovery and it will work?

Comment: Unbricking will take the phone back to how it was when you got it out of the box, and then you can choose to root it again if you want.  If you use the same method just download the custom Kernel (could try just this if using a modified stock kernel and see if it boots or skip this and go for custom ROM and Gapps replacing the factory ROM) ROM, Gapps, Recovery and whatever else then when you get to the point it boots to only recovery the files are already there.

Comment: Wait, couldn't I use the adb push to put the ROM files on my phone instead? Otherwise, I will try unbrick it and root again, install a rom and then try install TWRP again. But it will delete all my data? The only thing I care about is my photos, how can I transfer them to my computer from TWRP Recovery?

Comment: You could try it, but depends on if the recovery supports it.  ADB is a daemon that runs in the background so if you can not boot in to Android ADB is not available.  I think TWRP has tried to do something in allowing ADB during recovery, but I think it is a custom version and I don't know if it has access to the actual device storage (depends whats mounted which there is a mount menu in the recovery, but if only /recovery is mounted its only thing you could copy to which would not have enough room for much of anything and would not be accessible for installs).

Comment: It's not a bad thing to take the phone back to factory.  Yo already know how to root it, and yeah it's extra steps, but it is Friday and the weekend now just set aside a couple hours get the factory image and use an older Windows machine if your current one does not like the exe.  You can not put the exe on the phone it will do nothing for you the factory image is inside that exe and you need to run it to get what you need out of it your phone can't use it.

Comment: Which kernel/rom should I install to get out of the "soft brick", and if possible can you tell me how to instal, with TWRP Recovery? I will try putting the file on the phone with ADB. If that doesn't work I will take the phone back to factory. I don't really want to reset it to factory, since I want to keep my photos, but it won't matter that much if it's the only (and easiest) option to fix my phone.

Comment: I provided links to both a modified stock kernel and modified stock ROM for your phone in earlier comments.  Those links take you to the XDA threads where you can read the info about them if you wish before downloading.  They are not direct file download links.  You can also find more info on things like using ADB in recovery for your device possibly in the XDA QA threads.

Comment: I decided to do the factory reset with Odin. I connected my phone, ran Odin and put my phone into download mode. I then downloaded the firmware. It says it's a 1.7GB file, estimating 7 hours.. So I took my phone out of download mode by holding Power+Up+Down volume. I turned it back on, and some how it booted up normally. Any idea how putting my phone in download mode could have any effect? Restarted phone and still booted up. Should I try go in recovery mode and see if TWRP is still there?

Comment: @Mike may I suggest you go over all those comments and see what can be integrated with your answer, and then delete the ones of you that got obsolete plus "flag obsolete" those of Kamdroid which are no longer needed? Currently, it's a bit too long a tail of comments here :)